# How to chase down SyntaxError: missing = in XML attribute /Javascript/D3 v.3 / USA.gov's API

Tags: javascript, xml, json, d3.js

I'm making a graphic with D3.js.

I'm calling USA.gov's API for some JSON -- JSON Lint says it's valid: http://www.usa.gov/api/USAGovAPI/contacts.json/contact/49743/tree/branch

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>FED chart</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg canvas to the page
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([height, width - 160]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) {return [d.y, d.x]; });


d3.json("http://www.usa.gov/api/USAGovAPI/contacts.json/contact/49743/tree/branch", function (error, root) {
  //activity goes here
});  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting two errors:

1. SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8364'     d3.v3.js:1178
2. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d3     feds.html:16   //first reference to d3

I doubt #1; I doubt there's an error in d3.  The site is up fine.
So, for #2, I put my code in Firefox console.

It gives me:

SyntaxError: missing = in XML attribute.

XML?  Hm.  Where & how do y'all suggest I find this alleged missing character?

FWIW: Same errors in Chrome, Firefox & Safari; same error if I run script locally or if I turn on xampp.

FWIW2: I'm open to hard-coded solutions. I just want the .json once and am making a graphic for printing on paper.

Comment: This is one of those browser security things?  FWIW, Safari will load local .csv and .tsv.  I don't know if .json is any different, but I've tried saving the .json locally, opening in Safari and get the same problem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please rewrite the line where you link your html code with d3.js. It should read:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Part `charset="utf-8"` is missing.

After that, you should be ready to go. :)

Comment: Hm.  That's not working for me. But I hope/suspect this is the right track. I don't really understand encoding.

Comment: Here is the deal: Starting from around version 3, D3 source code contains special characters for mathematical constants like PI, EPSILON or similar. If you dont have  charset="utf-8" D3 will not be loaded, and you get all these errors.

Comment: So, what is the result? Did you try? Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: I know it sounds unbelievable, but I am almost positive that you have the exact problem that I described. :)

Comment: lol, I feel like my mom.  Turn off the whole computer & turn it back on and it works.  Thanks!